# What is wrong with this Postbuild event command?

Tags: visual-studio, post-build-event

This `PostBuild`event in Visual Studio works:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent"
        Condition="$(TargetFramework)=='net7.0'">
    <Exec Command="xcopy /y /d  &quot;$(ProjectDir)BM3DotNet64\*.dll&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)&quot;" />
</Target>
```

This however does not work:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="if $(TargetFramework)=='net7.0' ( xcopy /y /d  &quot;$(ProjectDir)BM3DotNet64\*.dll&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)&quot;)" />
</Target>
```

The point is that I want the code to xcopy all dll's from a different directory (`$(ProjectDir)BM3DotNet64`) when the `TargetFramework`==`net471`) so I want to add a `else` statement as well. Adding a second `<Target` element with a different condition also does not work: only the second one is executed.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Just move the condition to the Exec command, that way you can repeat it as often as needed.